# What is the use of need in "you'll need to help me"?

Tags: word-usage

All right... but you'll need to help me, Sirius,' said Lupin, 'I only know how it began...'

What's the difference between this and "I need your help". That one sounds like "the other person is going to need Lupin's help.

I don't understand.

Comment: Presumably Lupin is agreeing to do something that will benefit Sirius, but Sirius will need to help him to do it.

Comment: to need to do something=to have to do something.

Answer (score 1):

Sirius want Lupin to tell Harry Potter a story.

Lupin knows how the story begins, but he doesn't know how it ends.  Fortunately, his friend Sirius knows how the story ends.  So Lupin asks Sirius for help to tell the story.  Sirius can help by telling the ending of the story.

For Sirius to get what he wants, Sirius will need to help Lupin.

Of course, you need more context to know that is what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You could see that as an attempt transfer the Lupin's need of help to Sirius, as a way of obligating him/her.

Lupin has heard a request from Sirius for something. Lupin is saying that to supply what Sirius needs, some help is needed from Sirius. Since both of them want to satisfy Sirius, Lupin's need of help is a need that Sirius has to satisfy.

Answer (score 0):

"you'll need to help me" = "you will need to help me" (future; the help will be needed when he gets to that point in the story he's about to tell)

"I need your help" means in the present, right now (as in "I need your help getting started").  People sometimes say, "Help me out, here..." in these situations.